# Google Vision API does not recognize glasses 100%

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have one project that integrates with Google vision APIs.

I found that some photo images with wearing glasses, the Google Vision APIs can not detect at all. For my case I need to proof that every photos uploaded must not contain any glasses. [image]

This image, it seems that the Google Vision API can not detect wearing glasses at all.

Comment: I tried your image [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/), and you're right; it doesn't seem to detect that glasses are being worn by the model. Not surprising, these are frameless glasses, specifically designed to be less noticeable. :-) Did you try with any other photos? I tried with [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9BtX.jpg), and it detected eyewear with a probability of 100% and glasses with a probability of 98%.

Comment: Other photos with glasses, it works very well, except this clear glasses.